# ApplicationWindow with Toolbar cannot hold SwipeView because of import errors

Tags: qml, qtquickcontrols, qtquickcontrols2

I am using [Qt Opensource 5.10.0](http://doc.qt.io/) with [Qt Creator 4.5.0](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/) based on `ArchLinux 64bit.` and the [docs for ApplicationWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html#details) states it requires `QtQuick.Controls 1.4`:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    toolBar: ToolBar
    {
    }   // ToolBar
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

which compiles and runs ok. Now, I want to add [SwipeView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html#details) to upper `ApplicationWindow`, however `QtQuickControls 1.4` does not recognize it, as it also states in [SwipeView's docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipeview.html) and requires `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3`, so if I let `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4` in `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow
{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    toolBar: ToolBar
    {
    }   // ToolBar

    SwipeView
    {
    }   // SwipeView
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

I get error:

```
Starting /mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:15 SwipeView is not a type

/mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12 exited with code 255
```

and if use `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3`:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    toolBar: ToolBar
    {
    }   // ToolBar

    SwipeView
    {
    }   // SwipeView
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

I get following error:

```
Starting /mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:11 Cannot assign to non-existent property "toolBar"

/mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12 exited with code 255
```

Now, if I include both imports:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    width: 640
    height: 480

    visible: true

    toolBar: ToolBar
    {
    }   // ToolBar

    SwipeView
    {
    }   // SwipeView
}   // ApplicationWindow
```

I still get:

```
Starting /mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:12 Cannot assign to non-existent property "toolBar"

/mnt/projects/build-test12-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/test12 exited with code 255
```

as in second case.
The first error is logical, since in version `1.4` there was not `SwipeView`, however, why `QtQuick.Controls 2.3` does not recognize `ApplicationWindow`'s member/property [ApplicationWindow.toolbar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html#toolBar-prop) in second case?

Comment: Why don't you just use both of imports?  `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3 import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`. According to the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-applicationwindow.html) `ApplicationWindow ` requires `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4`

Comment: If I use both, I still get `toolBar` error, second case.

Comment: Can you please update your question with relevant code and errors you get using the code? It would be clearer and easier to run.

Comment: @folibis I've provided simple smallest example in the question already with errors.

Comment: Yes you say you use both of imports but I see 2 piece of code each one uses its own import. If I want to run the code to get the same error you get I have to write the code by myself instead of just copy your one.

Comment: @folibis Third example with both imports added.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this duality arose from the fact that there are 2 `ApplicationWindow`, one came from `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4` and the second one come from `import QtQuick.Controls 2.3`. The new one have no `toolBar` so you get the error.

If you still want to use the old one you can use aliasing as following:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Old

Old.ApplicationWindow {    
    toolBar: ToolBar
    {
    }
}
```

or you should use [ApplicationWindow.header](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-applicationwindow.html#header-prop) instead in the new one:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    header: TabBar {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I don't know why Qt changed the name from `toolBar` to `header`. For me it looks illogical.

Comment: wow, it works! However, do you maybe know, which file `ApplicationWindow` resides in for future checks?

Comment: "I don't know why Qt changed the name from toolBar to header. For me it looks illogical." - I would assume because it's not just desktop applications using `ApplicationWindow`, so a more generic name is better. Plus there's `footer`, so having a matching `header` makes sense.

Comment: Yes @Mitch, in that sense you're probably right. Is worth to think wider =)